# How to shorten this down? (methods)

Tags: android, xml, onclick, onclicklistener

Is it possible to make this code any easier/shorter?
We are using the code on 25+ objects.

```java
  Tekst = text and Knapp = buttons.
  final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_utesteder, container, false);
  exodusTekst = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.exodusTekst);
  exodusKnapp = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.exodusKnapp);

  exodusKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          exodusTekst.setVisibility((exodusTekst.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
          exodusImage.setVisibility((exodusImage.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
          fotballpubenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          ovenpoTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kvarteretTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          hulenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          sjobodenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          downstairsTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          garageTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          insideTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          finnegansTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kosmoTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          ricksTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          lilleTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          brukbarTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          finckenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          scotsmanTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          dreamsTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          metroTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          luuxTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          tidiTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          bryggenNightclubTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          felizTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          jacobAallTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kaosTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          calibarTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          fotballpubenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          ovenpoImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kvarteretImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          hulenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          sjobodenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          downstairsImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          garageImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          insideImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          finnegansImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kosmoImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          ricksImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          lilleImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          brukbarImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          finckenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          scotsmanImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          dreamsImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          metroImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          luuxImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          tidiImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          bryggenNightclubImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          felizImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          jacobAallImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kaosImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          calibarImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
  });
  exodusImage = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.exodusImage);

  exodusImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
          intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://goo.gl/maps/OEFPh"));
          startActivity(intent);
      }
  });
  fotballpubenTekst = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fotballpubenTekst);
  fotballpubenKnapp = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.fotballpubenKnapp);

  fotballpubenKnapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          fotballpubenTekst.setVisibility((fotballpubenTekst.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
          fotballpubenImage.setVisibility((fotballpubenImage.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
          exodusTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          ovenpoTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kvarteretTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          hulenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          sjobodenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          downstairsTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          garageTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          insideTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          finnegansTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kosmoTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          ricksTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          lilleTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          brukbarTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          finckenTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          scotsmanTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          dreamsTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          metroTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          luuxTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          tidiTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          bryggenNightclubTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          felizTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          jacobAallTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kaosTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          calibarTekst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          exodusImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          ovenpoImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kvarteretImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          hulenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          sjobodenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          downstairsImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          garageImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          insideImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          finnegansImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kosmoImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          ricksImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          lilleImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          brukbarImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          finckenImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          scotsmanImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          dreamsImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          metroImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          luuxImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          tidiImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          bryggenNightclubImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          felizImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          jacobAallImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          kaosImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          calibarImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
  });
  fotballpubenImage = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fotballpubenImage);

  fotballpubenImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
          intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://goo.gl/maps/h9mRw"));
          startActivity(intent);
      }
  });
```

Comment: If you have the elements inside Layouts, you could hide the complete layout so you will not have to hide element by element.

Comment: use a map where you store all your widgets and iterate them with a loop. Normally that looks much better then

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create one method that will do a trick:

```
private void hide(View... widgets) {
   for (View v: widgets) {
      v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
}
```

Equivalent for showing widgets (if you'll want to use it):

```
private void show(View... widgets) {
   for (View v: widgets) {
      v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
}
```

Since all widgets extends from `View` you can use without fear method(s) above for whatever widget.

**Usage (for your case):**

```
hide(exodusTekst, exodusImage, fotballpubenTekst, ovenpoTekst);
```

Comment: What does "widgets" represent?

Comment: @AndreasKvåle it represents your widget(s) passed to method as parameters. See updated answer.

Comment: What does (View v: "widgets") represent?

Comment: it loops though array passed as parameter, its called foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method for setVisibility for all images and then use that method.

or use all views in any layout and just that layout will be hide...

Answer (score 0):

If there are too many views to change why not creating two layouts and switch between them onclick by calling `setContentView()` and then `onResume()`, and move your `onCreate()` long implementation to `onResume()`